# How to encrypt password for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, passwords

I want add new user from another script and I need create password for Drupal7 users, I can't find exact function which is doing it on Drupal, what function is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With drupal 7, password are no more encrypted through md5.

There are several way to get/set a password in drupal7.

**Using drush** (for your information, not used in your case):

```
drush upwd admin --password="newpassword"
```

**Without drush, if you have a cli access to the server :** (for your information, not used in your case)

```
cd <drupal root directory>
php scripts/password-hash.sh 'myPassword'
```

Now copy the resultant hash and paste it into the query:

```
update users set name='admin', pass='pasted_big_hash_from_above' where uid=1;
```

**If you are working on a remote environment** on which you cannot connect, you can put this specified code in a file such as password.php such as this one:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/password.inc';
  print _password_crypt('sha512', $_GET['p'], _password_generate_salt(DRUPAL_HASH_COUNT));
  exit();
}
print "No password to hash.";
```

And then hit your site using: http://domain.tld/password.php?p='MyPassword'. The hash will appear on your browser's tab.
  Don't forget to remove it once you done it.

So, if you want to use some password function generation, have a look on [**_password_crypt()**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/function/_password_crypt/7) and [**_password_generate_salt()**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/function/_password_generate_salt/7)